# I have got additional 30px to the position

Tags: css

It is a copied code from an exercise, but I don't know why the header sets -30px beyond the right boarder of the viewport (doesn't happen on the video tutorial). I have tried applying 30px to the right, but it counts from 0 not from that additional pixels I got as a gift.

The Internet hasn't shown me any answers yet..

Please help.

As seen here it adds 30px on the right hand side, so the header (100% width) goes outside the viewport:
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yJnP.png)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 88px;
  position: fixed;
  right: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #FF825C;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #EA6044;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

header input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: #FFA473;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ToDoList app</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter an activity...">
    <button type="button" name="button"></button>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is your expected output? can you add screenshots

Comment: I replied below.

Comment: Try to add the screenshots as edits in your original post instead of posting a separate answer with them (since it's not an answer it's adding to the question).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You question goal is not clear. We don't know what you are trying to achieve, we just got a piece of code that works fine. Add a screenshot or something to help us to understand your problem. Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @teocci : It does not work in my browser, and in your website's part, 'run the code snippet', does not work neither. The header goes beyond the viewport (30px is added to the right position, so the width: 100% goes outside the viewport, as I said before.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you set the padding for all sides. Try to put right padding only and check:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
header {
    width: 98.5%;
    height: 88px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FF825C;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #EA6044;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  }

  header input {
    width: 99.5%;
    height:50px;
    float: left;
    background: #FFA473;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ToDoList app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter an activity..."/>      
      <button type="button" name="button"></button>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually need padding in all four directions. If I type them separately not in a general 'padding' it does the same.